# Decrease Docker Image Size

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

So I am trying to deploy a multi container service(web, worker, redis) using docker-compose to ECS. The service has a ML model which requires Tensorflow and Keras as dependencies. After running the pip install -r requirements.txt, the image size increases to more than 2gb, 1.75gb of which are dependencies. Is there a way to decrease this image size? Since deploying such a large image on cloud has a lot of cons?

Dockerfile for web:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR .
COPY . .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["python", "views.py"]
```

```
requirements.txt:
Flask==1.1.2
numpy==1.18.5
opencv-python==4.2.0.34
Pillow==7.1.2
redis==3.5.3
rq==1.4.3
boto3
pymongo
Keras==2.2.4
tensorflow==1.15.0
matplotlib
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your dependencies are causing the increase of 1.75GB you should start there. There is no easy silver bullet. These are the first steps:

1. See how much the individual dependencies increase the image. Start with biggest offender.
2. See if the dependencies allow for a different installation variants. Maybe there is a version that does not need the full library.
3. See if some parts of the dependencies can be deleted manually. If you do the deleting right after `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt && rm -rf somepath` the docker image will not grow.
4. Next you could search for a more optimized base image. You could try `python:3.6-slim` instead.

Comment: The biggest dependency is Tensorflow, but I need it cus my project is built around it. It takes up majority of 1.75gbs, so is there a way around it? for example instead using python 3.6 as my env, instead replace thet wih FROM tensorflow....?

Comment: Given that the tensorflow base image is less than 600MB that might be another path worth trying. That will be the equivalent of 2. and 3. Another option would be to re-build an even slimmer base image - but that will quite some work and nightmare to maintain.